# How to update embedded object of an array inside mongodb document using mongoid with ruby?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I want to update an embedded object of an array inside of mongodb collection using `ruby` and `mongoid`. I have an schema like this

```
{
  _id: 23234342,
  age: 23,
  customer_name: 'alex',
  email: 'alex@gmail.com',
  orders: [
    {
      reference_number: '10',
      amount: 2300,
      ordered_at: '01-01-2023 11:12:00'
    },
    {
      reference_number: '12',
      amount: 2300,
      ordered_at: '01-01-2023 11:12:00'
    },
  ]

}
```

Now i want to update the value of `amount` of `orders` object with `reference_number = 12`

I know i can do like this

```
Customer.where(_id: "23234342").elem_match(orders: { reference_number: 12 }).update("$set" => {"orders.$.amount" => 4000})
```

But i want the correct syntax in ruby mongoid for this query.

How can i achieve using ruby mongoid?